# ¿Puedo tener en un mismo equipo dos Servidores Web que son IIS y PM2?

Tags: servidor, iis, nginx, https, pm2

buena tarde.
Actualmente tengo un solo equipo que estoy utilizando como servidor de aplicaciones web, pero en el existen aplicaciones PHP que se administran desde IIS y se comunican por HTTPS mediante el puerto 443.

Ahora, a demás de las aplicaciones PHP quiero alojar en el mismo equipo aplicaciones Node js que se administraran con PM2 sin embargo no puedo utilizar HTTPS ya que este esta siendo utilizado por IIS y tengo que dar de baja un servidor web para levantar el otro.

¿Que puedo hacer para mantener activos ambos servidores web mediante HTTPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes tener tantos servidores como quieras (y soporte la capacidad de tu equipo).

Incluso si lo requieres puedes usar 2 o más con el mismo tipo de servicio. 
Solo hay que usar un número de puerto distinto para cada uno de ellos.

Siempre puedes definir un número de puerto alternativo, cuando 2 servicios utilicen el mismo... Digamos que usarás 2 servicios web (el puerto 80 es el oficial). Puedes usar el puerto 80 con uno, y otro número para el otro.

Todo cliente que quiera pedir algún recurso deberá especificar el número de puerto si no es el número oficial.

Comment: Agradezco tu ayuda Homero. Por curiosidad sabes que otro puerto puedo utilizar para HTTPS a parte del 443?.
Esto porque el 443 esta con IIS, entonces necesitaría un segundo para HTTPS que se utilice con PM2.